# Vertical Scrollbar shows on IE only

Tags: asp.net, css

I have developed a website that displays at least 50 rows in a grid and sometimes needs scrolling up and down. I have developed this on Visual Studio 2008, C# as code behind, and is testing this on IE. When I have published it, it still works well with IE but not with other browsers. I cannot scroll anymore. Do I need to change something on my css?

Here is my markup:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="NewGenericOnlineReport.aspx.cs" Inherits="CamstarReportPortal.WebForms.OnlineQuery.NewGenericOnlineReport" MasterPageFile="~/Common/SiteMaster.Master" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="multiColDD_List" Namespace="multiColDD_List" TagPrefix="ksj" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="multiColDD_List.DropDowns" Namespace="multiColDD_List.DropDowns"
    TagPrefix="ksj" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
<asp:Content ID="contentMain" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphContent">    
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../Scripts/CSS/myStyle.css" />
    <div>
        <h1>
            Online Query
        </h1>        
    </div>
    <div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td class="label">
                    Query Name:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Height="24px" Width="343px" 
                                    DataSourceID="sqldsUserQuery" DataTextField="USERQUERYNAME" 
                                    DataValueField="USERQUERYNAME" AutoPostBack="True"  AppendDataBoundItems="True"
                                    onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="" Value=""></asp:ListItem>
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                                <%--<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" Enabled="false" Width="400px" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                                <asp:DropDownExtender runat="server" ID="popupdropdown" DropDownControlID="pnlGrid" TargetControlID="DropDownList1">
                                </asp:DropDownExtender>
                                <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlGrid" Style="display: none; visibility: hidden">
                                    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4"
                                        DataKeyNames="UserQueryID,USERQUERYNAME" DataSourceID="sqldsUserQuery" style="table-layout:fixed;"  
                                        GridLines="None" 
                                        CssClass="mGrid" 
                                        AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt" Width="70%">
                                        <Columns>
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="UserQueryName" HeaderStyle-Width="10%" 
                                                ItemStyle-Width="10%" FooterStyle-Width="10%" HeaderText="UserQueryName" 
                                                SortExpression="UserQueryName" >
                                            <FooterStyle Width="10%" />
                                            <HeaderStyle Width="10%" />
                                            <ItemStyle Width="10%" />
                                            </asp:BoundField>
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderStyle-Width="10%" 
                                                ItemStyle-Width="10%" FooterStyle-Width="10%" HeaderText="Description" 
                                                SortExpression="Description" >
                                            <FooterStyle Width="10%" />
                                            <HeaderStyle Width="10%" />
                                            <ItemStyle Width="10%" />
                                            </asp:BoundField>
                                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Width="10%" ItemStyle-Width="10%" FooterStyle-Width="10%">
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:LinkButton CommandName="Select" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("UserQueryName") %>' ID="LinkButton1" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click"
                                                        runat="server">Select</asp:LinkButton>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                                <FooterStyle Width="10%" />
                                                <HeaderStyle Width="10%" />
                                                <ItemStyle Width="10%" />
                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                        </Columns>
                                        <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="alt" />
                                    </asp:GridView>
                                </asp:Panel>--%>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Button ID="cmdSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" 
                                    onclick="cmdSearch_Click" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Button ID="cmdExport" runat="server" Text="Export" 
                                    onclick="cmdExport_Click" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="label">
                    Description:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtBoxDescription" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" 
                        Width="99%" ReadOnly="True" Rows="3"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="label" valign="top">
                    Parameters
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="False" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <asp:GridView ID="gvParameters" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" style="table-layout:fixed;"  
                                          GridLines="None"
                                          CssClass="mGrid"                                           
                                          CellPadding="0" OnRowDataBound="gvParameters_RowDataBound"
                                          AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt">
                                <Columns>
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="userqueryparametername" HeaderStyle-Width="10%" HeaderStyle-CssClass = "hideGridColumn" ItemStyle-CssClass="hideGridColumn"
                                                    ItemStyle-Width="10%" FooterStyle-Width="10%" HeaderText="Parameter Name" 
                                                    SortExpression="userqueryparametername" >
                                                <FooterStyle Width="10%" />
                                                <HeaderStyle Width="10%" />
                                                <ItemStyle Width="10%" />
                                    </asp:BoundField>
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ParameterName" HeaderStyle-Width="10%" 
                                                    ItemStyle-Width="10%" FooterStyle-Width="10%" HeaderText="Parameter Name" 
                                                    SortExpression="ParameterName" >
                                                <FooterStyle Width="10%" />
                                                <HeaderStyle Width="10%" />
                                                <ItemStyle Width="10%" />
                                    </asp:BoundField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Parameter Value" HeaderStyle-Width="10%" ItemStyle-Width="10%" FooterStyle-Width="10%">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtParamValue" CssClass="text" Font-Size="Small" Text=' <%# Eval("DEFAULTVALUE").ToString() %>' runat="server" Width="97%"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                        <FooterStyle Width="10%" />
                                        <HeaderStyle Width="10%" />
                                        <ItemStyle Width="10%" />
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                </Columns>
                                <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="alt" />
                            </asp:GridView>
                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div>        
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" style="table-layout:fixed;"  
                      GridLines="None" OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging"
                      CssClass="mGrid" OnDataBound="GridView1_DataBound" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound"
                      AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt" AllowPaging="true" PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr"
                      Width ="100%" PageSize="50">
            <PagerSettings Position="TopAndBottom" />
            <PagerStyle CssClass="pgr" />
            <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="alt"></AlternatingRowStyle>
        </asp:GridView>

    </div>
    <div>
        <asp:SqlDataSource 
            ID="sqldsUserQuery" 
            runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CamstarOLTP %>"
            ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CamstarOLTP.ProviderName %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT uq.userqueryname
      ,REPLACE(uq.description,'ISRPT|','')description
      ,uq.querytext
      ,uq.userqueryid
FROM userquery uq
WHERE uq.objectcategory = 'ONLINEQUERY' AND SUBSTR(uq.description,0,5) = 'ISRPT'
ORDER BY uq.userqueryname">
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
        <asp:SqlDataSource 
            ID="SqlDataSource1" 
            runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CamstarOLTP %>"
            ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CamstarOLTP.ProviderName %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT uq.userqueryname
                              ,REPLACE(uq.description,'ISRPT|','')description
                              ,uq.querytext
                              ,uq.userqueryid
                           FROM userquery uq
                           WHERE uq.objectcategory = 'ONLINEQUERY' AND SUBSTR(uq.description,0,5) = 'ISRPT'
                                 AND uq.userqueryname = :que
                           ORDER BY uq.userqueryname">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList1" Name="que" 
                    PropertyName="Text" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
        <asp:SqlDataSource 
            ID="sqldsQueryParams" 
            runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CamstarOLTP %>"
            ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CamstarOLTP.ProviderName %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT uqp.displaytext ParameterName
                                  ,uqp.userqueryparametername
                                  ,uqp.defaultvalue
                                  ,uqp.dynamicvalue
                                  ,uqp.paramsequence
                                  ,uqp.useforblockrows
                                  ,uqp.userqueryid
                           FROM userqueryparameter uqp
                           WHERE uqp.userqueryid = :queryid
                           ORDER BY uqp.paramsequence">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="hfQueryID" Name=":queryid" PropertyName="Value" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqldsQueryResult" 
                           runat="server" 
                           ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CamstarODS %>"
                           ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CamstarODS.ProviderName %>">
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hfQueryID" runat="server" />
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hfQueryScript" runat="server" />
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hfIndex" runat="server" />        
    </div>
    <!--<div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function thirty_pc() {
                var height = $(window).height();
                var thirtypc = (100 * (height - 405)) / 100;
                thirtypc = parseInt(thirtypc) + 'px';
                $("#divContent").css('height', thirtypc);

            }

            $(document).ready(function() {
                thirty_pc();
                $(window).bind('resize', thirty_pc);
            });
        </script>
    </div>-->
</asp:Content>
```

Thanks!

Comment: how can we say while you don't place your markups what are you doing?

Comment: hello @C-Link my bad, I forgot to include it.